# more font with a few characters inside each

Tags: fonts, pdf

I hope I am not OT with my question ...
Why when I go to extract the fonts embedded in a pdf file I have several fonts with the same name (esGHJFGJ + NewTimeRoman "," IFEH + NewTimeRoman ") with a few characters inside each and not one that includes all the characters? Thanks

Comment: most likely you have included pdf with the fonts already sub-setted and pdftex wasn't able to merge the subsets so you end up with multiple subsets of the same font.

Comment: It’s also possible the subsets were loaded with different font options, such as one having small caps or one having old-style numbers?

Comment: thanks for the replies